# to include a header into result of sQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

i m running a sql query to select data from a table .

i want to include headers as the first  row in the result of the query.
headers will be coming from some other table or can we can sqlhardcode the values .

below is my query to fetch data.

```
 select invoice_type_code,
  shipper_short_code ,
  charge_type_code ,
  incurred_date  ,
  charge_amount  , 
  charge_description 
  from prepayment_charge_calc ;
```

i want a header above  data of first row of  every column.these header shouldnt be  the column name

for eg.

```
header1   header2   header3  header4   header5  header6  
 1          2           3          4        5        6
```

header 1 to 6 are coming from other table or can be the harcoded value .below  this header we should have the data extracted from "prepayment_charge_calc"
table  ..   1,2,3,4  are the data from "prepayment_charge_calc" table

can any one  suggest me the query for this .

Comment: You could use a `Union` to select those headers first, then union your query.

Comment: can u provide me a sample query to explain u r comment .it will helpful for me

Comment: So are you looking for a dynamic column names? or are you looking for a hard coded first row?

Comment: If you want to change the column name, just put `as mynewcolumnname` after your column.  You can name it whatever you want.  Its called an *alias*

Comment: i cant use alias  because column name may be a number or charcater.

Comment: can u provide me a sample code to explain  ur comment

Comment: what version of postgres are you using?

Comment: You can use an alias as a number if you quote it.  `incurreddate as "12343"`

Comment: Please consider marking an answer (the check mark under the votes) so we know which result helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any extra effort to have the column names in the header the way you want, just mention an `ALIAS` to the columns the way you want.

For example :

`select col1 as "header1", col2 as "header2".... from table`

In any `GUI/non GUI based tool`, the `scroll pane` automatically places the `table header` at the top of the `resultset`, which is actually the column headers you need.

Comment: if we are fetching this column name from  another table( let table is "abc") then what will be the change in the above queries .plz can anyone tell me

Comment: thanks for your help. If one column is blank then in the table"abc",then also it will fetch it.

Comment: If you mean that a column in table abc has all NULL values, then do not select the column if you do not want to project it.

Comment: No.if one of the column name is " " . and i want to use this as a column name . Then when i am calling my procedure from the front end (i.e Ms ACESSS) its giving me the error. MS acess is not able to map the column with column defined in the plsql procedure.

Comment: You cannot have that as column name, it is an invalid identifier.

Comment: first table is having 8 column and second table have 7 column then will these union query will work .if not then what may be the other method to do that

Comment: For the table with just 7 columns, have a pseudo column with a dummy value of same data type as that of other table's column in the union query.

Comment: but if i dont want to use union .so how should i make the query for above condition.

Comment: You can join the two tables, but to suggest further, I need more details about both tables. And, your question is now going into new direction. Why not post a new question? And vote the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming Oracle DBMS, you can create the header row manually using DUAL table and then union with the real data. Use a dummy psuedo-column ("rno" in the example below) to sort the data. However, you have to convert any other datatype to VARCHAR to make this work. Idea is illustrated below:

```
select
   'header1',
   'header2',
   'header3',
   'header4',
   'header5',
   'header6',
   1 rno
from
   dual
union 
select 
  invoice_type_code,
  shipper_short_code ,
  charge_type_code ,
  incurred_date  , --convert this using to_char if date datatype
  charge_amount  , --convert this using to_char if numeric datatype
  charge_description,
  2 rno
from 
  prepayment_charge_calc
order by rno;
```

Comment: if first table is having 8 column and second table have 7 column then will these union query will work .if not then what may be the other method to do that

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you want to be able to hardcode various different column names into your query.

In Oracle, you can do this with quotes:

```
 select 
  invoice_type_code as "1",
  shipper_short_code as "asdf",
  charge_type_code as "12353",
  incurred_date as "ddf",
  charge_amount as "234$", 
  charge_description as "header6"
 from 
  prepayment_charge_calc
```

You can see an [example of that here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6d1999)